# Set the position of the children of a gameobject to 0,0,0 in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following problem. I am using SceneManager to teleport my main character from a scene to another. Whenever i teleport him, it keeps teleporting to the object trigger position.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (!load)
        {
            load = true;
            StartCoroutine(ChangeScene(collider));
        }
    }
    IEnumerator ChangeScene(Collider collider)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneIndex, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        Scene nextScene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(1);
        GameObject gameobj = collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;

        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(gameobj, nextScene);
        gameobj.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        foreach (Transform child in gameobj.transform)
        {
            child.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        yield return null;
        SceneManager.UnloadScene(nextSceneIndex - 1);
    }
```

It doesn't matter the gameobject transform position location as its children will always reposition themselves to match the position of the trigger from before the teleportation. I don't understand why the children always modify their position anywhere the parent would be. Shouldn't they keep the same position inside the parent? I'm still new to Unity and i don't know a lot of stuff still i need some help.

Comment: A child's position is _always_ relative to its parent. Moving it to 0, 0, 0 will position it to the exact position of its parent. If you want to move it to absolute 0, 0, 0, unparent the child, move it and then reparent it.

Comment: i am trying to move it to 0,0,0 of the parent but it fly to -12.92416 9.4328 -248.3733 for some reason

Comment: I have tried to iterate through each children and set it`s position to 0,0,0. The debug is saying that it is at position 0,0,0 but when i pause the game to check the position it has some weird coordinates like the ones shown above and only the parent stays at 0,0,0

Comment: From what I can tell in your code, `gameobj` is set to _its_ parent, then that parent's position is set to 0, 0, 0, and then all its children get set to 0, 0, 0. Is that what you want to have happen?

Comment: It could be a problem with the transforms not syncing properly due to physics. Try turning on Auto Sync Transforms in the Project Settings > Physics > Auto Sync Transforms. This tells Unity whether or not to automatically sync transform changes with the physics system whenever a Transform component changes.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal The parents get set to 0 0 0 but the children get some random coordinates coresponding to the position of the Trigger position. For a better understanding, i have the above code set as script to a Cube in the first scene. After the  character teleports to the second screen it doesn`t take care of what vector position i give him.. it will always use the trigger object position.

Comment: @CodyC you`re a genius. that was the issue. Many thanks <3

Comment: Don't sweat it, it comes up a lot!

Comment: What also might have solved it was if you used `FixedUpdate` (since you're dealing with physics related things)! You could try setting `load` to true in the `OnTriggerEnter` function, and then in the `FixedUpdate` method check if load is true; if so then you can call the `ChangeScene` function. Also, why bother with the coroutine, and not just a normal function?

Comment: you might want to use localPosition, not position

Comment: @CodyC that was something i found in order to not use dontdestroy function and also not using singleton for moving to another scene and it was looking like it's working. I'll update to your idea and try it out to see the outcome. Thanks :)